# Accepting Objects containing specific method instead of accepting specific Type

Tags: java, generics, polymorphism, dynamic-typing

**[EDIT]: This question is about Types that I have no control over. So making them inherit a superclass or implement an interface is not possible. I want to be able to do this without wrapping the Types.**

I would like to write a method that accepts as a parameter all objects that contain a specific method.

For example, we have 2 completely different types that both contain the `get` method with the same signature:

```java
public class TypeOne {
  public int get() { /* Some implementation */ }
}

public class TypeTwo {
  public int get() { /* Some other implementation */ }
}
```

How can I write a method that will accept both of these types?

```java
public static int callGetOnObject(GettableObject gettableObject) {
  return gettableObject.get();
}
```

Comment: looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)

Comment: Could be. In javascript this is quite easy due to the dynamic typing, but I guess when using Java, or any other statically typed language, you are indeed out of luck.

Comment: XY problem == you ask about a possible solution without asking what you want to accomplish - maybe using  reflection (or AspectJ), but the question it is still unclear what exactly the real problem/intention is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there's no way to actually filter the incoming object by checking if they have a specific method, but you can use reflection to verify input, and then call the function. Here's an example:

```
 public static void ensureMethodThenCall(Object object, String methodName, Object... args) throws InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException{
    Method[] marr = object.getClass().getMethods();

    for(Method m: marr){
        if(m.getName().equals(methodName)){
            m.invoke(object, args);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While true, using reflection is almost always the wrong thing to do (there are very few exceptions).

Comment: @alfasin That could very well be the case, but this question was about the possibility to do so. This solution does work, the only thing that this does not provide is checking at compile time if the Objects you passed satisfy the requirement to have a specific method.

Comment: @Titulum you can also cross a rode blindfolded but that doesn't mean that it's a good idea. And yes, indeed you're right: by using reflection you don't get the benefits of compile time checks that you would otherwise, you also make your code slower to execute and more vulnerable to abuse. As previously stated, only in some very specific cases (e.g. writing a debugger) one should consider reflection.

Comment: I completely agree! But the question was not `Should I cross the road blindfolded?` but rather `How can I cross a road blindfolded?`. If one wants to know the answer to my question, the above answer is what they are looking for.

Answer (score 6):

First make the method non-static, and second have both classes implement an interface that has the `get` method. And last, change `callGetOnObject` to accept an instance of a class that implements that interface:

```
public interface Getter {
  int get();
}

public class TypeOne implements Getter {
  public int get() { /* Some implementation */ }
}

public class TypeTwo implements Getter {
  public int get() { /* Some other implementation */ }
}
```

And then:

```
public static int callGetOnObject(Getter gettableObject) {
  return gettableObject.get();
}
```

**EDIT:**

Since the question was modified here's the new answer: if you don't control this code and you're not willing to wrap it, then you're out of luck: no way to do it AFAIK.

Comment: Sorry, I updated my question to contain more information. I'm talking about doing this for types that I do not control, and that I can not extend to implement a common interface. I also removed the `static` keyword from the example Types. Those were indeed redundant.

Comment: @Titulum in that case, why is the objection to wrapping the types? that would have been my next suggestion...

Comment: Thank you, sorry for incorrectly constructing the question.

Comment: I just wanted to know if other solutions existed outside of inheritance and wrapping. No way to do this with generics? In Java 8, the compiler can succesfully subtitute a lambda as a `Predicate`, `Supplier`, etc. Maybe in this direction?